# Updating a Symfony app with Docker-compose without losing data

Tags: symfony, docker, capistrano3, docker-compose

I have a multi-container Symfony application that uses docker-compose to handle the relationships between the containers. To simplify a little, i have 4 main services :

```
code:
  image: mycode
web:
  image: mynginx
  volumes-from:
    - code
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  links:
    - php-fpm
php-fpm:
  image: myphpfpm
  volumes-from:
    - code
  links:
    - mongo
mongo:
  image: mongo
```

The "mycode" image contains the code of my application and is built from the following Dockerfile :

```
FROM composer/composer

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
            libfreetype6-dev \
            libmcrypt-dev \
            libxml2-dev \
            libicu-dev \
            libcurl4-openssl-dev \
            libssl-dev \
            pkg-config

RUN docker-php-ext-install iconv mcrypt mbstring bcmath json ctype iconv posix intl

RUN pecl install mongo \
 && echo extension=mongo.so >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mongo.ini

COPY . /code
WORKDIR /code

RUN rm -rf /code/app/cache/* \
 && rm -rf /code/app/logs/* \
 && chown -R root /code/app/cache \
 && chown -R root /code/app/logs \
 && chmod -R 777 /code/app/cache \
 && chmod -R 777 /code/app/logs \
 && composer install \
 && rm -f /code/web/app_dev.php \
 && rm -f /code/web/config.php

VOLUME ["/code", "/code/app/logs", "/code/app/cache"]
```

At first, deploying this application was easy. I just had to do a simple `docker-compose up -d` and it created all the containers and ran them without any issue. But then i had to deploy a new version.

This configuration uses volumes to store data :

- the source code is mounted on the /code volume, and shared between 3
  containers (code, web, php-fpm). It has to be replaced by a new version when deploying.
- the MongoDb data is on another
  volume, mounted only by the mongo container. I have to keep this data between deployments.

When i deploy an update to my code, i publish the new version of the *mycode* image and re-create the container. But since the */code* volume is still used by the *web* and *php-fpm* containers, the old volume can't be replaced by the new one. I have to stop all the running services to delete the old volume, and if i use the `docker-compose rm -v` command, it will delete the mongodb data too !
**Can't i replace only one volume with a new version, without any downtime ?**

So i'm kind of stuck here. I'm thinking of having a permanent volume to store the code and update it through SSH with Capistrano, old style. This will allow me to run doctrine migrations scripts after deployment too. But i have other issues with it as Capistrano uses symlinks to handle versions so i can't just mount the */current* folder to */code*.

- **Do you have a solution to handle the deployment of a Docker application without losing data and without downtime ?**
- **Should i use manual scripts instead of docker-compose ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the source code is mounted on the /code volume

This is the problem, it is not what you want.

Code never goes into a volume, it should change when the image changes. Volumes are for things that you want to preserve between changes to the image (data, logs, state, etc).

Code is the immutable thing that you want to replace when you change a container. So remove the `/code` volume from the `Dockerfile` entirely, and instead do an `ADD . /code` in the `mynginx` and `myphpfpm` Dockerfiles.

With that change, you can deploy with just `up -d`. It will recreate any container that have changed, and your volumes will be copied over. You don't need an `rm` anymore.

If you have your `Dockerfile` for `myphpfpm` and `mynginx` in a different directory, you can build using `docker build -f path/to/dockerfile .`

---

Using a host volume (as suggested in another answer) is another option, however that's not usually what you want outside of development. With a host volume you would still remove the `/code` `VOLUME` from the dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually very simple, i didn't think of that. The downside is that for keeping the code private i will have to create multiple private images on the repository and a free Docker hub account won't be enough. Thanks a lot !

Comment: That is the complete opposite. A volume is not only used for persistence, there's plenty of other reasons. Also, code does go into a volume, almost all production tools out there do this (complete opposite of what you said to not do this outside development), AWS ElasticBeanstalk as an example which is built on top of docker-compose mounts code from the host via a volume, see https://github.com/awslabs/eb-docker-nginx-proxy

Comment: Container volumes **should** only be used for persistence, maybe it's being used in other ways, but those uses are wrong.  You're right that host volumes can provide the code, but there are disadvantages. Instead of being able to distribute your application as a single image, now you're forced to distribute your code as well (doubling the work you have to do).  Sure it's possible, but it's not the suggested approach. The project you reference clearly says it s a demo, which is not a "production system".

Comment: It's a demo of how to run an app in production at AWS ElasticBeanstalk. Actually you're doubling the work by pushing the image and pulling it in the production server. That's a lot more work than just pushing the code to the production server and mounting it as a shared volume.

Comment: Like i said in another comment, this is a matter of opinion. The official Docker-compose documentation recommends hosting the code in images for production, not volumes. Of course you can do it with volumes too if you want. dnephin's answer solved my problem and follows the official Docker recommandation, why downvote it ?

Comment: I just found out that copying the code into the image is the official recommandation in the Docker Compose FAQ, and using volumes for development : https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/#how-do-i-get-compose-to-wait-for-my-database-to-be-ready-before-starting-my-application

Answer (score 0):

Do not copy the code via the Dockerfile, just attach volumes to the 'code' container.

Few edits:

```
code:
  image: mycode
  volumes:
    - .:/code
    - /code
web:
  image: mynginx
  volumes-from:
    - code
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  links:
    - php-fpm
php-fpm:
  image: myphpfpm
  volumes-from:
    - code
  links:
    - mongo
mongo:
  image: mongo
```

Same thing applies to mongo mount it to an external volume so it persists when the container shuts down. Actually there is also another method, they mention it in their dockerhub page https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/

> Where to Store Data
>
> Important note: There are several ways to store data used by
>   applications that run in Docker containers. We encourage users of the
>   mongo images to familiarize themselves with the options available,
>   including:
>
> Let Docker manage the storage of your database data by writing the
>   database files to disk on the host system using its own internal
>   volume management. This is the default and is easy and fairly
>   transparent to the user. The downside is that the files may be hard to
>   locate for tools and applications that run directly on the host
>   system, i.e. outside containers.
>
> Create a data directory on the host system (outside the container) and
>   mount this to a directory visible from inside the container. This
>   places the database files in a known location on the host system, and
>   makes it easy for tools and applications on the host system to access
>   the files. The downside is that the user needs to make sure that the
>   directory exists, and that e.g. directory permissions and other
>   security mechanisms on the host system are set up correctly.

Comment: The mongodb container method is actually just a volume that is created in their distribution without having to declare it in the docker-compose.yml file, so it's the same as my /code volume and would be erased by the "docker-compose rm -v" command. I already tried the method of mounting the source files from the Docker host but then i have to use another deployment tool, like Capistrano. And this comes with other issues like symlinks in volumes.

Comment: You can also mount mongodb via a volume to the host. You don't have to use Capistrano at all, why? What symlink issues? I've deployed several Symfony apps using this method, and they work perfectly.

Comment: If you store the code on the host machine, you have to deploy it to this machine first, and for that i used Capistrano. On my development machine i use this kind of binding but on production i would like to ship everything in images. The recommended way to store data in docker is through volumes and not shared folders, so i prefer sticking to that.

Comment: It's not shared folders it's shared volumes and the docker documentation has several examples of using shared volumes for adding your python webapps, where did you get this recommendation from? Shipping every iteration of your app via images is also wrong IMO, you're basically using it as a git repo. You'll have to push and pull the new image every deployment, or rebuild it from the Dockerfile which is severely time consuming. I used to do the latter, and with shared volumes it saves a lot of unnecessary wasted time.

Comment: If the `Dockerfile` is structured correctly (system dependencies first, code dependencies next, and code itself last), the time to rebuild is actually pretty quick (especially relative to download times).  The image is layered, so if only your code changes, you only have to download the code layer, which is going pretty small and should be fast.  If you don't put your code in the image you have to manage the dependency between code version and image version, which is unnecessary when they are packaged together in the image itself.

Comment: If there are official examples of using a container volume for code, we need to fix those.  Using a host volume for code is likely for development environment examples.

Comment: You can layer it as much as you want, I work in a big Symfony project where we have a lot of dependencies. Running compose install even with a composer.lock file and a GitHub token takes a lot, and the project can become huge. Now imagine uploading the image, and issuing a pull on the prod server. Lots of wasted time, which is critical for us. I used to use the method you are mentioning with single Docker containers at AWS and switched to shared volumes and Docker multicontainers.

Comment: This guy had the same problem as me http://blog.ionic.io/docker-hot-code-deploys/ and using volumes saved his time. And he's right about Docker being about the infrastructure, Docker is not your app.

Comment: It's more a matter of opinion, the official docker-compose documentation recommends the opposite for production: http://docs.docker.com/compose/production/ "_Removing any volume bindings for application code, so that code stays inside the container and can’t be changed from outside_". I'm not against having my code on the host but if you don't deploy your code with a tool like Capistrano, what is your deployment procedure ?